# how to exclude null from JSON? (after converting from XML)

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net, xmlserializer

Below is code to convert xml to json using http://json.codeplex.com/

how to exclude null from JSON? (ie         "SessionId": "null")

```
string xml = ""; //see XML value below
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc); //See Json value below
```

Xml Input

```
<MyResponse>

    <Timestamp>2012-01-07T12:43:29</Timestamp>

    <SessionId></SessionId>

</MyResponse>
```

Json Output

```
{"MyResponse":{"Timestamp":"2012-01-07T12:43:29","SessionId":null}}
```

Comment: how do I exclude "SessionId":null? or return this instead {"MyResponse":{"Timestamp":"2012-01-07T12:43:29","SessionId":""}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a simple string replace since you are outputting the JSON as a string. Do something like this:

```
jsonText = jsonText.Replace("null", "\"\"");
```

That should replace every occurrence of null with "".

Answer (score 0):

It is not giving null property like this. It gives like nil to true as attribute in xml element.